# can not find other's home directory in linux

Tags: linux, permissions

I work on a scientific-linux-system cluster together with many other users. The interesting thing is (under /home directory) I can only see my own folder and it looks like the other users' home folders do not exist at all. But I know they do have home directory under /home/ with mode 755.

I am not an expert in linux. I think it can be realized by the command "chflags", but I just wonder if it is possible to hide these folders by editing some system files like /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow.

Any reply would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is chroot used there?

Comment: @RaFD No, I am quite sure they are under the exact directory where my home folder is.

Comment: are you sure that there is read bit for others user on home dir (permission 755 as you wrote?). When you list (ls -l) /home/ dir what is an outuput?

Comment: @RaFD ls -la at /home/ shows only the information of my folder. But another user showed me his output of doing the same thing, so I know his permission is 755. And actually he could see my folder, but his folder is invisible to me.

Comment: What filesystem is used in home and, are there any other mounts in a point of your dir?

Comment: @RaFD Interesting. This might be the key point. I just checked the mount commend and find this line: compute-2-0.local:/export/data/users/***g on /home/***g type nfs (rw,noatime,rsize...) It looks like my folder is a mounted point and the file system is nfs, while /home/ itself should be ext4. But still I cannot understand why I cannot see others' home. My home folder is visible to everyone, but for the rest users, they can not see each others home.

Comment: The easiest example which I can give you: You have two users: user1, user2 (every home user is exported by nfs), on one machine both exports (user1,user2) are mounted, but on your machine only your export is mounted (e.g. user1).

Comment: @RaFD Thank you very much. I think I got the idea. we connect the cluster through ssh. So some one's export is mounted only when he is connected to the cluster. Is it what you are saying

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm saying (I gave only example but I don't know exact configuration of whole environment) but this thing which you mentioned is auto mount and can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can find all user names and their home folders in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: or just `eval echo ~$USER`

Comment: @HuStempHrrr Yes, I know. And /etc/passwd says their home folders are under /home/, but it seems they are invisible to me. I think they hide them in some way, so I want to know if there is any hidden property of a directory like "invisible". Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Inkling could you show one of the item in you passwd? put some `*` at the end if you want some privacy.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr e***q:x:511:100:Evan ***er:/home/e***q:/bin/bash This is the passwd line for one of the users on that cluster(I replaced some letters with *). As you can see, there is nothing abnormal. But his home folder (which is supposed to be under /home) is invisible to me